# Using undocumented classes such as NSPreferences in Mac App Store

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, mac-app-store

There is an undocumented class called [`NSPreferences`](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSPreferences) that appears to be used by Safari and Mail, and eases creation of multipage preference pages.

Has anyone had experience using `NSPreferences` or similar undocumented, but useful and fun, features in an application submitted to Mac App Store?

Comment: If you want to use this class in Mac App Store apps, you should file an enhancement request asking for it to be made a public API. https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @Peter Hosey: thanks, I'll do that :-)

Comment: Posted enhancement request: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1137408 - rdar://9161716

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't waste your time. From the [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

**2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected**

Comment: Thanks! I was however wondering if anyone had experience with actually getting the code through and not being rejected.

Comment: Look at it this way. Imagine that you've submitted something to the app store that uses private API, and wonder of wonders it was nevertheless approved. Are you going to blab about it on stackoverflow.com? Even if your username doesn't indicate your identity, and even if you've never mentioned your product, and even if Apple probably wouldn't notice, it just wouldn't seem prudent.

Comment: And even if you get away with it once, there's no sense in expecting to get away with it again. Counting on the reviewers to miss your violations of the rules is neither a good development practice nor a good business model.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoting everyone. Too bad. NSPreferences looks really useful. I wonder why it's not documented and publicly available.

Comment: Creating a class for a public framework is a lot more work than creating one for internal use. You can always tell your colleagues: "You can use this, but don't do x, y, or z." That doesn't fly with public classes. Also, sometimes a project has an immediate need for a class like NSPreferences, but the framework architects have a different long term plan. It's not a big deal for one organization to revise any apps that use NSPreferences, but once it's public they're locked into supporting it for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Transmit and Coda might both use it by the look of their Preferences dialog. Both are available on the App store.

Alternatively, you should check the OmniGroup framework library.

https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniAppKit/Preferences.subproj

It implements a very similar looking preferences dialog.

Comment: I've managed to implement it myself a long time ago ;) Not very difficult to do using a tabview, a toolbar and NSView animations. Question primarily referred to actual use of `NSPreferences` itself. Still, here's an upvote for a newcomer - welcome to SO!